# Add buttons to the row currently being edited

Tags: button, javafx, tableview, javafx-2

I have tried searching both google and stackoverflow for answer to my question but I could not find any.

I have a program that adds/reads data from a database and to a tableview. I want to be able to edit the previously entered data from the tableview by adding two buttons (Save and abort) to the current row being edited.

I am having some troubles understanding the routines like Callback etc. But I have managed to get a column with two buttons to appear when I start the edit. But I get buttons on every column I just want the buttons on the currently

selected row. Also I don't really understand how to get the current object from the save-button to be able to save it. 
And also how the abort-button should work to cancel all changes.

```
public void setUpTableView() {
    columnAnkomstdatum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("arrivalDate"));
    columnSupplier.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("supplier"));
    columnRadiopharmaceutical.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("radiopharmaceutical"));
    columnActivity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startActivity"));
    columnCalibrationdate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startDate"));
    columnBatchNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("batchNumber"));
    columnContaminationControl.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("contaminationControll"));
    columnRoom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("room"));
    columnUser.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("user"));

    tableview.setEditable(true);
    columnSupplier.setEditable(true);
    columnSupplier.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(supplierList));
    columnSupplier.setOnEditCommit(t -> {

        ArrayList<Radiopharmaceutical> radioListfromSupplier = new RadiopharmaceuticalDao().getRadiopharmaceuticalsBySupplierName(t.getNewValue().getSupplierName());
        radioList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(radioListfromSupplier);
        t.getRowValue().setSupplier(t.getNewValue());
        columnRadiopharmaceutical.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(radioList));

        if(tableview.getColumns().size() <= 9) {
            addButtonsToTable();
        }

    });

}

private void addButtonsToTable() {

    TableColumn<RegRadio, Void> editRow = new TableColumn<>("Edit");
    tableview.getColumns().add(editRow);

    Callback<TableColumn<RegRadio, Void>, TableCell<RegRadio, Void>> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<RegRadio,Void>, TableCell<RegRadio,Void>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<RegRadio, Void> call(final TableColumn<RegRadio, Void> param) {
            final TableCell<RegRadio, Void> cell = new TableCell<RegRadio, Void>() {

                private final Button btnSave = new Button("Save");
                private final Button btnAbort = new Button("Avbryt");

                {
                    btnSave.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                        RegRadio rr = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                        System.out.println("Saved");
                    });
                }
                {
                    btnAbort.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                        System.out.println("Abort");
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        HBox pane = new HBox(btnSave, btnAbort);
                        setGraphic(pane);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };
    editRow.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

    tableview.getColumns().add(editRow);
}
```

[image: Before Edit] 
[image: After Edit]

Comment: Also I get an error: "Duplicate TableColumns detected in TableView columns list with titles 'Edit'," When running the program.

Comment: You get that error because you add the column but never remove it, thus when you try to add it again it detects a duplicate column. To keep things simple you can keep the edit column there instead of dynamically adding/removing upon editing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `updateItem` callback you can check if the cell is in the selected row in order to decide if you should show the buttons or not. Additionally you also need a flag to check if the user is editing. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);        
    var selectedCells = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();

    if (empty || !isEditing || selectedCells.isEmpty || getTableRow().getIndex() != selectedCells.get(0).getRow()) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {    
        HBox pane = new HBox(btnSave, btnAbort);
        setGraphic(pane);
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to change the visibility of the buttons depending on whether the cell is in the selected row:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {    
        HBox pane = new HBox(btnSave, btnAbort); 
        var selectedCells = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
        pane.setVisible(!selectedCells.isEmpty() && getTableRow().getIndex() == selectedCells.get(0).getRow())
        setGraphic(pane);
    }
}
```

(I haven't compiled and tested these code samples)